# rendering video with Adobe After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I bought an effect on Videohive (http://videohive.net/item/classic-music-visualizer-/13342497), and create a 1h long video with music and picture in background.

I'm trying to render this video, but the estimate time for this is more than 10h... Also the filesize is huge (8GB for 5min of video!). How can I render/e
These are my settings:

[image]

Could you help me with settings to render/export video to normal filesize? I need video for publish on YouTube (but it must be 1920x1080 and good sound).

Answer (score 1):

Within the video format optionss, check and set the `Limit data rate` to `10000 kbps`. This will produce a file under 400 MB.

Comment: I tried your recommendation and the file was 2,8GB, but the quality was very bad :/

Comment: Can you post screenshots from the rendered file, as well as [mediainfo](http://www.mediaarea.net) report?

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering to an all I-frame codec first and then compress to h.264 later. Use proRes since you're on a mac. This will be a larger file, but you can delete it after you compress if you need the space. All I-frame codec encode every frame separately, whereas h.264 uses the similarities between different frames to reduce the file size, which doesn't work well with the way AE renders frame-by-frame.

This workflow also means that if you need to change your compression settings you don't have to re-render the whole thing again, just re-compress the master.